# How do I keep track of the score and check the answer?

Tags: java

```
I trying to make a math quiz game that generates random question and keep track of of what question are wrong and write.

I trying to figure out how to make my program respond if the answer written in the text field is correct or incorrect when I click the JButton `answerbutton`. I'm very new to using `ActionListener`.
```

ok so i got action listener to work but when i type in a answer it say my answeris wrong, even though it right. the first question that appear work fine but after that it , it say all my answer are wrong and it still wont keep track of my score.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

        import java.util.Random;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

        public class PracticeMath extends JFrame {
            Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random generator = new Random();
            protected JButton excerciseButton = new JButton( "New Excerices" ); // start new quiz session
            protected JButton answerButton = new JButton( "Answer" ); // set new question, check if the answer correct or wrong
            protected JLabel titlelabel = new JLabel( "How much is: " ); 
            protected int correctcounter = 0; // keep track of correct answer
            protected int wrongcounter = 0; // keep track of wrong answer
            protected int one = generator.nextInt(10);//generate ranodm first number of question
            protected int two = generator.nextInt(10); // generate random second number of question
            protected int i = generator.nextInt(4); // generate random operator
            protected char[] ops = { '+', '-', '/', '*' }; // the math operator
            protected JLabel correctlabel = new JLabel(" Number of Correct Answer: ");
            protected JLabel wronglabel = new JLabel( " Number of  Wrong answers:  " );
            protected JLabel firstnum = new JLabel("" + one); // display first number
            protected JLabel secondnum = new JLabel("" + two); //  display second number
            protected JLabel randomOP = new JLabel("" + ops[i]); display operator
            protected JLabel equalOP = new JLabel("=");
            protected JTextField answerText = new JTextField(); //text area for writing you answer
            protected JLabel questionmark = new JLabel("?");
            protected JLabel correct = new JLabel(""+ correctcounter); // display correct answer
            protected JLabel wrong = new JLabel(""+ wrongcounter); // display wrong answer
            protected JLabel commentlabel = new JLabel(""); // set a comment for how good you doing. optionial




            public PracticeMath(){

                answerText.setColumns(5);

                JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel();// add a panel
                FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) Panel1.getLayout();// layout for panel
                getContentPane().setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5)); // set layout
                getContentPane().add(Panel1); // set panel
                titlelabel.setForeground(Color.ORANGE); 
                titlelabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));

                Panel1.add(titlelabel);
                firstnum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                Panel1.add(firstnum);

                randomOP.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                Panel1.add(randomOP);

                secondnum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

                Panel1.add(secondnum);

                equalOP.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                Panel1.add(equalOP);

                Panel1.add(answerText);

                questionmark.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                Panel1.add(questionmark);

                Panel1.add(commentlabel);



                JPanel Panel3 = new JPanel();
                FlowLayout flowLayout3 = (FlowLayout) Panel3.getLayout();
                flowLayout3.setHgap(15);
                getContentPane().setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
                getContentPane().add(Panel3);
                Panel3.add(excerciseButton);
                Panel3.add(answerButton);



                    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                panel2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Statistic"));
                getContentPane().add(panel2);
                panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
                panel2.add(correctlabel);
                panel2.add(wronglabel);
                correct.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                correct.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                panel2.add(correct);

                wrong.setForeground(Color.RED);
                wrong.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                panel2.add(wrong);




            answerButton.addActionListener( this );

            }






           public static void main(String[] args) {

                PracticeMath frame = new PracticeMath();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400,400);
                frame.setTitle( "Math Practice");
                frame.setVisible(true);





            }

         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
   {
       String answer = answerText.getText();
       int answerint = Integer.parseInt(answer);
       if(one + two == answerint){
            correctcounter++;
            System.out.println("correct");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));


        }
       else if(one-two == answerint){
            correctcounter++;
            System.out.println("correct");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
        }
        else if(one * two ==answerint){
            correctcounter++;
            System.out.println("correct");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
        }else if(one/two == answerint){
            correctcounter++;
            System.out.println("correct");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
        }
        else{
            wrongcounter++;
            System.out.println("wrong");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your buttons do some desired action, like you say, you will need to use an ActionListener.  To do this, you will want to define some class that implements the ActionListener interface.  This class can be your PracticeMath class, if you want it to be.  So do this:

```
public class PracticeMath extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{...}
```

When you do this, your PracticeMath class will be responsible for specifying a definition to any methods that are part of the ActionListener interface; in this case

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
{
    // put something intelligent here
}
```

You then need to add this ActionListener to whichever buttons you want it to listen to.  Namely

```
answerButton.addActionListener( this );
```

Use "this" as the argument since your ActionListener is your PracticeMath class.  Now, when you press the answer button, whatever code you put into your actionPerformed(...) method will be called.  So you can evaluate your answer within.

Update to reflect the comment below:

Here is what your code should look like for the actionPerformed method.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
{
    String answer = answerText.getText();
   int answerint = Integer.parseInt(answer);
   if(one + two == answerint){
        correctcounter++;
        System.out.println("correct");
        one = generator.nextInt(11);
        two = generator.nextInt(11);
        // I don't know if you actually store the operator anywhere
        operator = ops[generator.nextInt(4)];
        firstnum.setText("" + one);
           randomOP.setText("" + operator);
           secondnum.setText("" + two);
    }
   else if(one-two == answerint){
       // ... and do the same for the other cases too
```

This, ofcourse, does not address the fact that you are not checking to see if the correct operator was actually used, but this should fix the problem with every answer past the first one being labeled as incorrect.

Comment: ok so i got action listener to work but when i type in a answer it say my answeris wrong, even though it right. the first question that appear work fine but after that it , it say all my answer are wrong and it still wont keep track of my score.

Comment: @DevendraDannyRamdayal Ok, having taken a closer look at your code, I see a few problems which *may* be causing it to not work.  First, I noticed that all the numbers you are using are integers.  If you divide an int by and int, you will get the floor (rounded down) of the answer.  Another thing that strikes me as odd is the way you check the answer. It will accept the answer regardless of what operation you perform on the two operands. You don't check to see what the actual operator was supposed to be. The strange thing is, this error would cause it to say incorrect answers were correct.

Comment: @DevendraDannyRamdayal  Okay... I have caught the problem. After the first question, you fail to set the values of "one" and "two" within the actionPerformed method.  You set the JLabels, but you don't set the values that you are comparing.  They remain what they were in the first question.  So, if you put the same answer every time, it should always tell you that you're correct.

Comment: thank for all help i really appreciate it but i still not able to keep track of the score on my gui

Comment: @DevendraDannyRamdayal To keep up with score (number correct and number incorrect) you just have to update your JLabels in the actionPerformed method.  You are already incrementing your correctCounter and wrongCounter variables.  Now you just need to update the text of the label that displays those values.